# Running BlackBerry 10 simulator (alpha) in virtualbox

Tags: blackberry-simulator, blackberry-10

Blackberry 10 (alpha) is providing the [Simulator](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/devzone/resources/) to run on [vmware](http://www.vmware.com/), I was wondering if that can also be run on [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)?

Comment: Good question, but I don't think VB has support of the Simulator files. They only allow creation of virtual machines, I think. Though I hope that at some point in the future, they'll implement a feature such as vmware's player.

Answer (score 10):

I tried to simply mount the hdd in Virtualbox (OS set to QNX) and while the boot sequence seems to work just fine I'm stuck at "Start Service: Screen" 
Probably unable to load the graphics server...

So the answer seems to be no, it does not work. Sadly.

Answer (score 1):

I tried that too and I think is a problem with the screen. Try to disable 3D acceleration. It comes enabled by default in the BB 10 alpha simulator vm.

If that does not work you can alway use VMware player. It is free and the simulator runs well. I am using it with Ubuntu 12.04 x64. I have to run in alpha safe mode because of the 3D acceleration but except for that, it works good.

https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/5_0

Comment: VMware player is **not** freeware any more